# Where I can find conda yml keys?

Tags: configuration, conda

Conda lets you define a yaml configuration file in order to create a new environment, [here an example](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually).
I was wondering where I can find a doc reference about yaml keys to use, like `name`, `channels` and `dependencies`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Valid Keys for YAML Environment Definitions

The valid keys are not comprehensively documented anywhere that I know of, but here's one way to find them:

```bash
# activate your base env first
$ conda activate
(base) $ python -c "import conda_env.env as env; print(env.VALID_KEYS)"
# ('name', 'dependencies', 'prefix', 'channels', 'variables')
```

Judging from [the code for key validation](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.9.2/conda_env/env.py#L43), all other keys will simply be ignored, though a warning will be raised to the user.

### Descriptions

- **name**: If this is provided, this will be the name of the environment. This can be overridden with the `--name|-n` argument.
- **prefix**: As an alternative to the **name** key, one can instead use this key to specify a location at which to install the environment. The **name** key will take precedence. While this does get output in `conda env export` commands, most users will not use this because it is a path. However, it might be useful when Conda is deployed as part of a larger software package, and the developers may wish to precisely control environment installation locations.
- **channels**: This key allows users to specify alternative channels to search when resolving dependencies.
- **dependencies**: This key allows for specifying packages to install. This variable accepts a list of strings (package names), as well as a sublist for `pip install` commands, for example:

  ```
  dependencies:
    - python
    - pip
    - pip:
      - foo
  ```

  Note that the values under  `- pip:` will be parsed and placed into a temporary `requirements.txt` file, which is subsequently passed to `pip install -r <tmp_requirements.txt>`. This means that in addition to PyPI packages, one can also put GitHub packages or even separate files of `requirements.txt` for Pip to install. See [the Advance Pip Usage example](https://github.com/conda/conda/tree/4.9.2/tests/conda_env/support/advanced-pip). Also, be aware that [the best practice recommendation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#pip-in-env) is to use Pip sparingly.
- **variables**: Added in Conda v4.9, this allows one to specify environment variables that will be set and unset upon environment activation and deactivation, respectively. See [the documentation on environment variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables).