# How to convert a conda env yaml file to a list of requirements for a settings.ini file accounting for channels and conversions for pypi

Tags: python, pip, conda, nbdev

**NOTE**: you can start at [Problem formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76352457/how-to-convert-a-conda-env-yaml-file-to-a-list-of-requirements-for-a-settings-in/76352458/#problem-formulation). The motivation section just explains how I found myself asking this.

## Motivation

I use and love [nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/tutorial.html). It makes developing a python package iteratively as easy as it gets. Especially, as I generally do this along side a project which uses said package. Does this question require knowledge of [nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/tutorial.html)? **no**. It only motivates why I am asking. Normally when I create a new [nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/tutorial.html) project (`nbdev_new`), I get a `settings.ini` file and `setup.py` file. In order to keep working on different packages / projects simple, I will immediately create a [conda environment file](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) `env.yml` for the project (see `Files > Example Conda File` [maybe this link works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76352457/how-to-convert-a-conda-env-yaml-file-to-a-list-of-requirements-for-a-settings-in/76352458/#example-conda-file)).

I know that the environment one develops a package in is **NOT** necessarily the minimum dependencies it requires. Further, a package's dependencies are a subset of those one may *need* for a working on a project utilizing said package. In **MY** use case it is clear that I am double-dipping! I am *developing* the package as I *use* it on a project.

So for the sake of this question let's assume that the `package dependencies == project dependencies`. In other words, the `env.yml` file contains all of the `requirements` for the `setting.ini` file.

### nbdev workflow

1. make new empty repo "current_project" and clone it
2. `cd path/to/current_project`
3. `nbdev_new`
4. make `env.yml` file
5. create / update environment:

```bash
# create conda environment
$ mamba env create -f env.yml

# update conda environment as needed
$ mamba env update -n current_project --file env.yml
# $ mamba env update -n current_project --file env.mac.yml
```

6. active environment:

```bash
# activate conda environment
$ conda activate current_project
```

7. install `current_project`:

```bash
# install for local development
$ pip install -e .
```

## Problem formulation

I am developing a package in python using a `setup.py` file.  My package may have requirements (listed under `settings.ini` with the key `requirements`) that get automatically important and used in the `setup.py` file. While developing my package I have a conda environment which is specified in a yaml file `env.yml` (see `Files > Example Conda File` [maybe this link works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76352457/how-to-convert-a-conda-env-yaml-file-to-a-list-of-requirements-for-a-settings-in/76352458/#example-conda-file)).

I also have some GitHub actions that test my package. I dislike having to update `settings.ini` manually (especially since it doesn't allow for multiple lines) to get the requirements into `setup.py`. **Especially** as I have already listed them out nice and neatly in my `env.yml` file.  So my question is as follows:

### Question

> Given a conda environment yaml file (e.g. `env.yml`) how can one iterate through its content and convert the dependencies (and the versions) to the correct `pypi` version (required by `setup.py`), storing them in `settings.ini` under the keyword `requirements`?

**caveats**:

- version specifier requirements in conda are *not* the same as `pypi`. Most notably `=` vs `==`, amongst others.
- package names for conda may not be the same for `pypi`. For example [`pytorch`](https://pytorch.org) is listed as [`torch`](https://pypi.org/project/torch/) for `pypi` and [`pytorch`](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch) for conda.
- the environment yaml file may have channel specifiers e.g. `conda-forge::<package-name>`
- the environment yaml file may specify the python version e.g. `python>=3.10`, which shouldn't be a requirement.
- **MY** ideal solution works with my workflow. That means the contents of `env.yml` need to get transferred to `settings.ini`.

## Desired outcome

My desired outcome is that I can store all of my package requirements in the conda environment file `env.yml` and have them automatically find themselves in the `setup.py` file under `install_requires`. Since my workflow is built around reading the requirements in from a `settings.ini` file (from [nbdev](https://nbdev.fast.ai/tutorials/tutorial.html)), I would like the solution to take the values of `env.yml` and put them in `settings.ini`.

**Note** I am sharing my [current solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76352458/5623899) as an answer below. Please help / improve it!

## Files

### Example conda file

```yaml
# EXAMPLE YAML FILE

name: current_project
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge  
  - fastai

dependencies:  
  - python>=3.10

 # Utilities
 # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - tqdm
  - rich
  - typer

  # Jupyter Notebook
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - conda-forge::notebook
  - conda-forge::ipykernel
  - conda-forge::ipywidgets
  - conda-forge::jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
  
  # nbdev
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - fastai::nbdev>=2.3.12

  # PyTorch & Deep Learning
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - pytorch>=2
  # NOTE: add pytorch-cuda if using a CUDA enabled GPU. You will need to 
  #       remove this if you are on Apple Silicon
  # - pytorch::pytorch-cuda
  - conda-forge::pytorch-lightning

  # Plotting
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - conda-forge::matplotlib
  - conda-forge::seaborn
  
  # Data Wrangling
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - conda-forge::scikit-learn
  - pandas>=2
  - numpy
  - scipy    

  # Pip / non-conda packages
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - pip
  - pip: 
    # PyTorch & Deep Learning
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    - dgl
```

Comment: I find the most straightforward Conda to PyPI mapping is to create the Conda environment, then run `pip list --format=freeze` in the resulting environment. I’m not familiar with the `.ini`, but if it’s Python-only packages, then the pip requirements is probably a better starting point than parsing a Conda YAML. For me, it’s all about straightforward code to maintain, rather than computational efficiency, especially since it’s something that runs infrequently.

Comment: @merv thank you for your time and expertise! I know with conda you can export the entire list of packages. Since I am starting with the `env.yml` file, is there a way to just export, with conda, the list of pypi packages (and their dependencies). As for the `pip list --format=freeze`, basically the same thing. I don't need to explicitly list every package, just those specified in the conda file.

Answer (score 1):

## Current Solution

The current solution is the file `env_to_ini.py` (see `Files > env_to_ini.py` [maybe this link works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76352458/5623899#env_to_ini.py)).

**NOTE** this solution uses [`rich`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html) and [`typer`](https://typer.tiangolo.com) to create an informative command line interface (CLI) which will show you which dependencies were added, changed, removed, or unchanged. This should make working with the script easier (especially should there be bugs in it) as it has not been extensively tested.

### How to use `env_to_ini.py`

Assumptions:

- `env.yml` or `env.mac.yml` under project root
- `settings.ini` under project root
- `env_to_ini.py` under project root

This script is provided so that if the `env.yml` (or `env.mac.yml`) file changes you can automatically update the dependencies of the `current_project` package (under `settings.ini`) to match.

```bash
# default usage
$ python env_to_ini.py

# show packages that didnt change
$ python env_to_ini.py  --unchanged  

# specify a different environment file
$ python env_to_ini.py  --unchanged  --file=env.mac.yml
```

### Caveats

This is a bit hacky. You can modify it per project as needed. The so called "hackiness" is primarily located under the two `TODO`s, which I will now explain. **Note** that `TODO` 2 is more important than `TODO` 1.

#### TODO 1: exclusion

Search for the following in the provided script:

```py
# TODO: IMPROVEMENT 1: utilize a list of packages to exclude.
#       by default this would include python and pip.
```

Per the original question, some packages are to be excluded from the conda environment file `env.yml`. Namely, `python`. Under the first `TODO`, which achieves this *currently* via an `if / elif / else` statement, you could change the script to accept an additional argument containing package to exclude, or read in an additional file containing these.

**NOTE**:
It is unclear to me that if you were to modify your `env.yml` file to have a section *after* `dependencies` called `ignore` if it would mess up your usage with conda. e.g.

```yaml
dependencies:
  - python>=3.10
  # - ...
ignore:
  - python
  - pip
  # ...
```

#### TODO 2: mapping

Search for the following in the provided script:

```py
# TODO: IMPROVEMENT 2: utilize a map of packages to rename.
#       by default this would include pytorch --> torch.
#       Ideally, this would figure it out automatically.
```

Per the original question, some packages need to be renamed because their package name on conda is **different** than it is on `pypi`. The example give is [`pytorch`](https://pytorch.org) which is listed as [`torch`](https://pypi.org/project/torch/) for `pypi` and [`pytorch`](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch) for conda.

Under the function `requirements_to_ini` this is *currently* achieved by using an `if / elif / else` statement. You could change the script to accept an additional argument containing package to rename, or read in an additional file containing these.

**NOTE**:
It is unclear to me that if you were to modify your `env.yml` file to have a section *after* `dependencies` called `rename` if it would mess up your usage with conda. e.g.

```yaml
dependencies:
  - python>=3.10
  # - ...
rename:
  - pytorch,torch
  # ...
```

**NOTE**:
It is unclear to me how you could determine this automatically per your question's desired outcome.

## Files

### env_to_ini.py

```py
# env_to_ini.py

import yaml
import configparser
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table

import typer
from typing import Optional, Tuple

app = typer.Typer()
console = Console()


# NOTE: utility function to print colored text
def cprint(style:str, text:str) -> None:
    console.print(f"[{style}]{text}[/{style}]")

def has_channel(requirements_str:str) -> bool:
    return '::' in requirements_str

def extract_channel(requirements_str:str) -> Tuple[Optional[str], str]:
    channel = None    
    if has_channel(requirements_str):
        channel, requirements_str = requirements_str.split('::', 1)        
    return channel, requirements_str

def is_not_valid_package_char(s:str) -> bool:
    return not (s.isalnum() or s in ['-', '_', '.'])

def split_str_at_first_non_alpha(s:str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    idx = next((
            i for i, char in enumerate(s) 
            if is_not_valid_package_char(char)
        ), len(s))
    return s[:idx], s[idx:]

def split_package_version(s:str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    # NOTE: alias for split_str_at_first_non_alpha
    return split_str_at_first_non_alpha(s)


# NOTE: this parses requirements from the settings.ini file. Thus there is one line and each package is separated by a space.
def parse_requirements(requirements_str):
    requirements = {}
    for req in requirements_str.split():
        package, version = split_package_version(req)
        requirements[package] = version
    return requirements

# NOTE: this parse depdencies form the env.yml file.
def extract_packages(dependencies):
    packages = {}
    for dep in dependencies:

        if isinstance(dep, str):
            channel, package_version = extract_channel(dep)
            package, version = split_package_version(package_version)


            # TODO: IMPROVEMENT 1: utilize a list of packages to exclude.
            #       by default this would include python and pip.
            
            # NOTE: we do not need to add python to the requirements
            if package == 'python':
                continue

            # NOTE: likewise we do not need pip
            elif package == 'pip':
                continue


            packages[package] = version
        
        elif isinstance(dep, dict):
            for key, values in dep.items():                
                if key == 'pip':
                    for pip_dep in values:                        
                        package, version = split_package_version(pip_dep)                        
                        packages[package] = version                        
    return packages

# NOTE: check if the depdencies in the env.yml file vary from the ones in the settings.ini file.
def compare_requirements(old, new):
    added = {k: v for k, v in new.items() if k not in old}
    removed = {k: v for k, v in old.items() if k not in new}
    changed = {k: (old[k], new[k]) for k in old if k in new and old[k] != new[k]}
    remained = {k: (old[k], new[k]) for k in old if k in new and old[k] == new[k]}
    return added, removed, changed, remained

# NOTE: I like pretty terminals
def print_changes(added, removed, changed, remained):
    table = Table(title="Changes")
    table.add_column("Package", style="cyan")
    table.add_column("Old Version", style="magenta")
    table.add_column("New Version", style="green")
    table.add_column("Status", style="yellow")

    for package, version in added.items():
        table.add_row(f':package: {package}', "", version, "Added")
    for package, version in removed.items():
        table.add_row(f':package: {package}', version, "", "Removed")        
    for package, versions in changed.items():
        table.add_row(f':package: {package}', versions[0], versions[1], "Changed")
    for package, versions in remained.items():
        table.add_row(f':package: {package}', versions[0], versions[1], "Unchanged")

    console.print(table)


def requirements_to_ini(requirments:dict) -> str:
    ini = ''
    for package, version in requirments.items():
        # TODO: IMPROVEMENT 2: utilize a map of packages to rename.
        #       by default this would include pytorch --> torch.
        #       Ideally, this would figure it out automatically.

        # NOTE: this is a hack to make the env.yml file compatible with the settings.ini file
        #       since the env.yml file uses pytorch and the settings.ini file uses torch.
        #       Add more elif statements if you need to change other package names.
        if package == 'pytorch':
            package = 'torch'

        if version:
            ini += f"{package}{version} "
        else:
            ini += f"{package} "
    return ini


@app.command()
def update_requirements(
    file: Optional[str] = typer.Option(
        'env.mac.yml', 
        help="YAML file to extract the new requirements from.",
    ),
    unchanged: Optional[bool] = typer.Option(
        False,
        help="Whether to print all packages, including the ones whose versions haven't changed.",
    ),
):
    # NOTE: notice that file is `env.mac.yml` and not `env.yml`. Now with Apple Silicon I have 
    #       one env file for more common CUDA versions and one for Apple Silicon.
    
    cprint("bold cyan", f"Loading environment yaml file {file}...")
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        env = yaml.safe_load(f)


    # NOTE: read in the current dependencies from the conda env.yml file
    cprint("bold cyan", "Extracting packages and their versions...")
    new_requirements = extract_packages(env['dependencies'])

    # NOTE: read in the previous requirements from the settings.ini file
    cprint("bold cyan", "Loading settings.ini file...")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('settings.ini')

    cprint("bold cyan", "Comparing the old and new requirements...")
    old_requirements = parse_requirements(config['DEFAULT']['requirements'])

    # NOTE: check for changes
    added, removed, changed, remained = compare_requirements(old_requirements, new_requirements)

    # If --unchanged option is given, print unchanged packages as well
    if unchanged:
        print_changes(added, removed, changed, remained)
    else:
        print_changes(added, removed, changed, {})

    # NOTE: update the requirements in the settings.ini file
    cprint("bold cyan", "Updating the requirements...")
    config['DEFAULT']['requirements'] = requirements_to_ini(new_requirements)

    cprint("bold cyan", "Saving the updated settings.ini file...")
    with open('settings.ini', 'w') as f:
        config.write(f)

    cprint("bold green", "Successfully updated the requirements in settings.ini!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

## Update `env2ini`

Now it is a CLI on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/env2ini/), [conda](https://anaconda.org/dsm-72/env2ini), [github](https://github.com/dsm-72/env2ini), and ["docs"](https://dsm-72.github.io/env2ini/)

Comment: RE: including extra sections in YAML, last I checked the code, Conda will safely ignore with a warning. Discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65243743/570918. If exploiting that, I’d probably use the first key as effectively a namespace, and use subkeys to pass the actual information.

Comment: @merv this comment and your answer both get an upvote ^•^. Thank you for the guidance. When you say first key as a namespace do you mean like a nested dictionary?

Comment: Yes, YAML supports structure if you want to use it. You can have, for example, a key like `nbdev:` and then have different sections like `rename:` under that. It would make sense for the mappings themselves to be key-value pairs. But my comment is mainly about future proofing where you store metadata in the YAML - pick a unique key to store that extra info in. I can’t recall now, but I’ve definitely seen specialized platforms that extend the Conda YAML to incorporate additional metadata.